# how to Collect data from two tables using joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables 
table 1 structure: [ logs ] 
userid  ||  clicks  || date || XXX   || XXX  ||| 
table 2 structure : [ user ] 
username  ||  email  || date || XXX   || XXX  |||

I want to display data like this

username, COUNT(clicks)

I am using the query below.

```
SELECT `user.username`,`userid`, COUNT(`userid`) as `total` 
FROM `logs` 
    INNER JOIN user ON logs.userid=user.userid 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Kindly quide

After the first reply , I modifed the query and aplied it , like this

```
 $sqlptcwall=mysql_query("SELECT user.username, COUNT(ptcwalllogs.userid) AS total FROM logs INNER JOIN user ON user.userid = ptcwalllogs.userid GROUP BY user.username ORDER BY COUNT(ptcwalllogs.userid) DESC
LIMIT 5");



<?php
echo "</tr>";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlptcwall)) 
      {
echo "<tr> ";
     echo "<td>" .$row[userid] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
     }
echo "</tr> " ;
?>
```

Error:
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Just add a `group by [some_field]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user.username, COUNT(user.userid) AS total
FROM logs
    INNER JOIN user ON user.userid = logs.userid
GROUP BY user.username
ORDER BY COUNT(user.userid) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: edited the question with more details and errors that i am receiving

Comment: The issue you have now is outside the scope of the original question. Read the error message carefully and check your data access code.